# Old animated movie with boy that has adventures in VR-like environments, using a pod in a science lab

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

So I am looking for an old animated movie that was probably from the 1960~1990s. I do not think it is Disney, but I could be wrong. It looks like a 80s or 90s cartoon movie but I believe it was just a standalone movie. I keep trying to find it but have not had any luck.

The movie starts out with a boy in a jungle adventure. He is going down a river. At some point this ends, and it turns out that the boy was using some kind of machine to have this adventures. It's in some kind of science lab. Kind of what we would call virtual reality now. It kind of looks like a pod. As the boy is exiting this device, climbing out of it down a staircase, then there is a big flash and accident.

He then meets this character that is like an angel. He helps the boy and they go through different adventure sequences. One sequence has them driving a car around a mountain area that is like a James Bond knock-off. There is a part where the car uses jump jets. I think they crash through a gate at some point. This angel-like character keeps telling the boy its very important for him to protect him.

I also remember that there is a character that is a metaphor for a demon. I think their name is Grim. There is a final fight were it is like a Star Trek knock-off with ships that end up crashing into each other. Its like these two entities (the angel and demon) are fighting for protection or destruction of this boy in this dream-like reality. Anyway the boy wakes up in bed and recalls to his parents that they won't believe his story.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this? Also, did you see it on TV, VHS, or some other home media format? If it was on TV, which country and language did you watch it in?

Comment: Hello, thank you. Hmm I know I watched it on VHS in the 1990s. Maybe in the mid or late 1990s but think it might have come out before then. In English.